# Is there a tool to output each line of a PHP script as it's executed?

Tags: php, debugging

I am looking for a function or other tool (but not debug) that can write all the lines which run/execute in a PHP file in the order they were run. Is there something like this?

Comment: Ok, because when I running debug I enter to  some function allot ,enter and out,enter and out from the function. in  deferent section on different files and this cause to me to not focus on the order of the program ,fore me to see the code line by line more comfortable. And debug will Fill the gaps

Answer (score 3):

No, but xDebug lets you step through the program code one line at a time in conjunction with a suitable IDE such as Netbeans or Eclipse.

Comment: Additionally, [xDebug Code Coverage](http://xdebug.org/docs/code_coverage) might be helpful.